# Using the pHYs chunk in PNG

Tags: png

I'm writing a PNG file from C++. I just achieved it, but I have one last problem: I would like to set the physical size of the pixels. I tried using the `pHYs` chunk, but it doesn't change anything in PNG readers I tried. Here is the data I put in the chunk, indicating that I would like my pixels to be 2cm x 2cm:

```
00 00 00 09 // the size = 9 bytes
70 48 59 73 // the string "pHYs"
00 00 00 32 // the number of pixels per unit on x axis = 50
00 00 00 32 // the number of pixels per unit on y axis = 50
01 // the unit: 1 = meter
4e a7 e4 73 // the CRC of the chunk
```

I put the chunk between the `IHDR` and the `IDAT` chunks.

Are my PNG readers (Xviewer, Okular and Pix) bad or am I making a mistake?

Comment: I apologize for my bad english.

Comment: `pHYs` is an ancillary chunk: PNG decoders are not required to support it, and many (most?) do not